# How to access a js file in a dll from a html file in the same dll

Tags: javascript, c#, html, internet-explorer, dll

I have a .html file in a dll and need to refer a .js file in the javacript folder in the same dll.

I tried using this in the html file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/popup.js"></script>
```

But getting script error.

How should I refer the js file in html?

Below I have attached the contents of dll

[PMP.dll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NnW3.png)

Comment: `.html file in a dll`?? Means??

Comment: I have embedded the html file in a dll

Comment: This needs a LOT more information on the overall use case.

Comment: I am creating an IE addon in c# project. I have a html file and some js and css files to be included in the html file. I have embedded all these files to a dll(Dynamic Link Library) so that I can deploy in target machine. Now I couldnot refer the js file in html file.

Answer (score 0):

You can drop type="text/javascript" from the script file as for **HTML5** javascript is the default script.Also make sure script tag is in head and src is pointing to correct path or use absolute path by copying from properties as shown in the below image.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
        <html>
            <head>
                <script src="/javascript/popup.js"></script>
            </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: How can I point source to the correct path when the js is inside a dll?

Comment: @Manobala,Can you just show the js file snapshot or dll which contains js file

Comment: I have attached the snapshot of dll

Comment: Why cant you put js files in another folder called scripts and then refer it ?.Just my opinion

Comment: Still getting the same error. I guess its trying to refer from a wrong location. I error I get the URL as about:/scripts/pmp_my_popup.js

Comment: copy the js file,create a new folder in Visual studio project and add the js file there and as soon as you click src in script tag,Visual studio will prompt you the path.

Comment: Did that only. But it picks local url only. But I could not access it from dll.